# convert getJson to table and make sortable WITHOUT plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I am very close here. This sort function works on a regular HTML table, but when I try load my table using getJson it does not work, and I am hoping this is due to my lack of knowledge in the realm of jQuery and JS. Hopefully I am not headed down the wrong path completely. Here is the code. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="catTable"></div>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var TableIDvalue = "indextable";
                var TableLastSortedColumn = -1;
                function SortTable() {
                var sortColumn = parseInt(arguments[0]);
                var type = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : 'T';
                var dateformat = arguments.length > 2 ? arguments[2] : '';
                var table = document.getElementById(TableIDvalue);
                var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                var arrayOfRows = new Array();
                type = type.toUpperCase();
                dateformat = dateformat.toLowerCase();
                for(var i=0, len=rows.length; i<len; i++) {
                  arrayOfRows[i] = new Object;
                  arrayOfRows[i].oldIndex = i;
                  var celltext = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[sortColumn].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]*>/g,"");
                  if( type=='D' ) { arrayOfRows[i].value = GetDateSortingKey(dateformat,celltext); }
                  else {
                    var re = type=="N" ? /[^\.\-\+\d]/g : /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
                    arrayOfRows[i].value = celltext.replace(re,"").substr(0,25).toLowerCase();
                    }
                  }
                if (sortColumn == TableLastSortedColumn) { arrayOfRows.reverse(); }
                else {
                  TableLastSortedColumn = sortColumn;
                  switch(type) {
                    case "N" : arrayOfRows.sort(CompareRowOfNumbers); break;
                    case "D" : arrayOfRows.sort(CompareRowOfNumbers); break;
                    default  : arrayOfRows.sort(CompareRowOfText);
                    }
                  }
                var newTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
                for(var i=0, len=arrayOfRows.length; i<len; i++) {
                  newTableBody.appendChild(rows[arrayOfRows[i].oldIndex].cloneNode(true));
                  }
                table.replaceChild(newTableBody,tbody);
                } // function SortTable()

                function CompareRowOfText(a,b) {
                var aval = a.value;
                var bval = b.value;
                return( aval == bval ? 0 : (aval > bval ? 1 : -1) );
                }
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    var output='<table id="indextable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
                        output+="<thead>"
                        output+="<tr>";
                        //output+="<th> HeadShot </th>";
                        output+='<th><a href=' + "javascript:SortTable(1,'T');" + '>Breed</a></th>';
                        output+='<th><a href=' + "javascript:SortTable(1,'T');" + '>Country</a></th>';
                        output+='<th><a href=' + "javascript:SortTable(1,'T');" + '>CoffeePreference</a></th>';
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</thead>"

                    for (var i in cats) {
                        output+="<tbody>" 

                        output+="<tr>";
                        //output+="<td><img src='" + cats[i].picture+"' alt='cat picture'></td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].breed + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].country + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].coffeePreference + "</td>"
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</tbody>" 

                    }
                    output+="</table>";
                    document.getElementById("catTable").innerHTML=output;


              });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: How are you testing your code? The `$.getJson` does not work with local files if you're testing it without a web server.

Comment: I definitely am testing on server.

Comment: I am getting output but the sort isn't working. http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~robinetm/testJson.html